# Differentiate between .h and .sh with find and regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, redhat

I am trying to remove files with certain extensions from a directory. The command I am using is not able to differentiate between .h and .sh. Where can I improve my regex?

This is my current command:

```
find directory/ -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*.(java|[hc]|cpp|hpp|cc|hh)'
```

Currently this returns .csh and .sh files. I do not want that to happen. When I remove "[hc]" this fixes the problem, but then I cannot find any .c or .h files. I have also tried

```
find directory/ -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*.(java|h|c|cpp|hpp|cc|hh)'
```

but this returns .csh and .sh files as well.

Comment: You might try to escape the dot `.*\.(java|[hc]|cpp|hpp|cc|hh)`

Comment: btw `[hc]` is identical to `h|c`

Comment: @Thefourthbird That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add an end of input anchor:

```
find ... -regex '.*\.(java|h|c|cpp|hpp|cc|hh)$'
```

This makes the list an absolute list of extensions, rather than just a *prefix* of the extension.

Comment: @code sure, but making the minimum change emphasises the solution, and there’s readability problems I have with your suggestion too - it’s much easier to see what’s going on when you simply list what you want. Also, you could build the plain regex from the contents of a file quite easily; when you micro-optimise you often lose the elegance of simplicity

Comment: @CodeManiac your RegEx wrongly matches the last two test strings here: https://regex101.com/r/CeVi16/1

Comment: You can make it to work by using backreference but yeah that will be ugly as @Bohemian suggested, if you want to see working one [`Ugly regex :p`](https://regex101.com/r/CeVi16/2)